# How do I identify this numeric value using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

So for each of these rows, there is a "xxx Answers" element.

How can I extract the numeric value of it so that I can do a comparison like:

if x > 50 then blah blah.

Comment: Please provide sample data in *text format*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the xpath to get the value.

```
//div[@class='u-text--gray-light-metadata']/a
```

Python code should look something like this (you have multiple answer elements 1 per each name so you have to get elements and iterate but here I am giving sample how to get the first one)

```
text =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='u-text--gray-light-metadata']/a)[1]").text
# extract the number of answers
answers = text.split(' ')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

A rough general solution that should catch all of them:

```py
import re
import selenium

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://example.com/") # your website here

anchors = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

matches = []
for anchor in anchors:
    match = re.fullmatch(r'(\d+) Answers?', anchor.text)
    if match:
        matches.append(match.group(1))

print(matches)
```